# Trying to upload a file(PDF) to data base using (React,Laravel)

Tags: reactjs, laravel

React:

```
function SendRequest(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/Stagires/Requestes/Finder/${StagiaireId}`)
        .then(data => {
                if (!data.data.success) {

                   
                    const formData      = new FormData(e.target);
                    const Message       = formData.get('message')
                    const StagiaireCV   = formData.get('CV')
                    console.log(Message, StagiaireCV);
                    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/Requestes',{'Acc_id':StagiaireId, 'Message': Message, 'StagiaireCV': StagiaireCV} )
                } else {
                    alert("You already sent a request!");
                }
            });
    };
```

React - form:

```
<form onSubmit={SendRequest}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="message">Ton Message</label>
                    <textarea id='message' placeholder='Message' name='message'></textarea>
                </div>
                <div onClick={AddCv}>
                    <input ref={file} id="file" type="file" name="CV" style={{ display: 'none' }}/>
                    <div>
                        <span className="material-symbols-outlined">download</span>
                        <p>Ajouter votre CV</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" >Envoyer la demande</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

And for laravel:
First api:

```
Route::get('/Stagires/Requestes/Finder/{id}', function ($id) {

    $data = Stagiaire_acc::find($id);
    $Requests = $data->Requests;
    if ($Requests) {
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['success' => false]);
    };

});
```

And the second api:

```
Route::post('/Requestes', function (Request $request) {

    $dataReq = Requests::create(
        [
            'Acc_id'      => request('Acc_id'),
            'Message'     => request('Message'),
            'StagiaireCV' => request('StagiaireCV')->file()->store('cv'),
            'RequDate'    => date('Y-m-d'),
        ]
    );

    return response()->json($dataReq, 200);
});
```

When ever I submit the the file it keep responding with:
"Call to a member function file() on array"
I tried my best and couldn't find a solution, hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: use `request()->file('StagiaireCV')`

Comment: I got this response:
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'StagiaireCV' cannot be null (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `Requests` (`Acc_id`, `Message`, `StagiaireCV`, `RequDate`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, test, ?, 2023-04-05, 2023-04-05 10:07:27, 2023-04-05 10:07:27))"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently using this code fixed it:
function SendRequest(e) {
e.preventDefault()

```
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/Stagires/Requestes/Finder/${StagiaireId}`)
    .then(data => {
            if (!data.data.success) {

                const formData      = new FormData();
                formData.append('Acc_id', StagiaireId)
                formData.append('Message', e.target.elements.message.value)
                formData.append('StagiaireCV', e.target.elements.CV.files[0])

                axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/Requestes', formData )
                .finally(alert('The request has been submitted!'))
            } else {
                alert("You already sent a request!");
            }
        });
};
```

---

Route::post('/Requestes', function (Request $request) {

```
$dataReq = Requests::create([
    'Acc_id' =>  $request->input('Acc_id'),
    'Message' => $request->input('Message'),
    'StagiaireCV' => $request->file('StagiaireCV')->store('cv', 'public'),
    'RequDate' => date('Y-m-d'),
]);

return response()->json($dataReq, 200);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
 Route::post('/Requestes', function (Request $request) {
    
        $dataReq = Requests::create(
            [
                'Acc_id'      => request('Acc_id'),
                'Message'     => request('Message'),
                'StagiaireCV' => $request->file('StagiaireCV')->store('cv'),
                'RequDate'    => date('Y-m-d'),
            ]
        );
    
        return response()->json($dataReq, 200);
    });
```

try this

Comment: Now I'm getting this response instead:
"Call to a member function store() on null"